# Third test case PHP for loop does not increment

Tags: php, algorithm, array-algorithms

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target. I've tried a few modified versions of the solution below.

```
function twoSum($nums, $target) {
    $arr = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($nums); $i++){
        
        if($nums[$i] + $nums[$i+1] == $target){
            array_push($arr, array_search($nums[$i], $nums), array_search($nums[++$i], $nums));
            break;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

When passed three test cases the first two return the correct outcome the last case returns the first correct index but the last index is (technically) incorrect.

Test cases used:

1. nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9

   expected output: [0,1]

   actual output: [0,1]
2. nums = [3,2,4], target = 6

   expected output: [1,2]

   actual output: [1,2]
3. nums = [3,3], target = 6

   expected output: [0,1]

   actual output: [0,0]

Comment: I assume it's incorrect because you don't want it to be allowed to use the same index twice? You'd have to keep a record of which indices have already been used, or remove them from the array, before searching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect because you assume 2 consecutive indices can lead to a target value in this line, which is incorrect. The pair could be any combination.

```
$nums[$i] + $nums[$i+1] == $target
```

It is also not considering index out of bounds exception for `$i + 1`. Rest of the code would surely go in incorrect direction anyway.

---

The steps to solve this is pretty straightforward.

- Use a simple associative array, say `$set` which will store key as the array element and value as the index of that element in the array.
- Now, when looping over the array, if `target - current_element` key(the other number) exists in the `$set`, you got the pair.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function twoSum($nums, $target) {
    $set = [];
    foreach($nums as $index => $curr_element){
        $cousin_value = $target - $curr_element;
        if(isset( $set[ $cousin_value ] )){
            return [  $set[ $cousin_value ], $index ];
        }
        $set[ $curr_element ] = $index;
    }
    return -1;
}

print_r(twoSum([3,3],6));
```

Comment: Thanks, why does my version work except on the last iteration; in the last array the last two values are in consecutive order but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ericacodes It is because you are doing array_seach which isn't needed if  i and i +1 already make a pair